# Pandas Seaborn diverging palette - making 0 neutral and positives green and negatives red

Tags: python, html, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

In Python Pandas, I want to create a table which displays the background gradient as red when negative numbers and green when positive numbers, meanwhile 0 is white. I want to use a diverging_palette with Seaborn so there are different shades of green and red.

I have a Dataframe, let's call it A that I have made into a pivot table.

Then I create the style of the table:
`cm = sns.diverging_palette(12.9, 126.8, s=100, l=53, center="light", as_cmap=True)`

I'm trying to customize the background gradient to my criterias:

```
def background_gradient(s, m, M, cmap=cm, low=0, high=0):
   
 rng = M - m
    norm = colors.Normalize(m - (rng * low), M + (rng * high))
  
  normed = norm(s.values)
  
  c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    
return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

    
htlm = A.style.apply(background_gradient cmap=cm) \

.set_table_styles(styles).render()

`return htlm`
```

However, the output displays numbers close to 0 as the wrong colour (i.e. some positive numbers are red and vice versa). Also, all 0's are red when I want them to be neutral (white).

How do I customize it so ALL positive numbers are different shades of green (the higher number the darker green) and red for negatives?b Is there any way to set 0 as "neutral"?